# how to fetch only a row from a mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

i allways end up doing this

```
$q = "select whatIwant FROM table where id = 'myId'";
$r = mysql_query($q);
while($i = mysql_fetch_array($r){
   /* iterate just one withem */
   $j = $i['whatIwant'];
}
echo $j;
```

how is this usually done? (i just want to avoid the unecessary loop)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In addition to the correct answers, there are multiple ways to handle this:

- If you add `LIMIT 1`, the result set will only contain one row and the `while` loop will terminate after one iteration:

  ```
  $q = "select whatIwant FROM table where id = 'myId' LIMIT 1";
  $r = mysql_query($q);
  while($i = mysql_fetch_array($r)) {
     $j = $i['whatIwant'];
  }
  echo $j;
  ```
- If you call `mysql_fetch_array` without a loop, you will get the first row of the result set:

  ```
  $q = "select whatIwant FROM table where id = 'myId'";
  $r = mysql_query($q);
  $i = mysql_fetch_array($r);
  $j = $i['whatIwant'];
  echo $j;
  ```
- If you add `break` to the loop body, the loop will terminate after one iteration.

  ```
  $q = "select whatIwant FROM table where id = 'myId'";
  $r = mysql_query($q);
  while($i = mysql_fetch_array($r)) {
     $j = $i['whatIwant'];
     break;
  }
  echo $j;
  ```

You can also combine these approaches (although using `break` is not really elegant in this case).

The best approach is using `LIMIT` and omitting the `while` loop, as [@zaf shows in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9657846/218196). This makes the code clearer and avoids unnecessary operations in the database.

Answer (score 9):

You can specify the number of rows in the sql query using the 'LIMIT' syntax.

Also, you can just remove the while loop and get the first row returned - if thats all you want.

For example (without returned value checking):

```
$q = "select whatIwant FROM table where id = 'myId' LIMIT 1";
$r = mysql_query($q);
$i = mysql_fetch_array($r);
print_r($i);
```

Answer (score 3):

add `LIMIT X, Y` where X is your starting row and Y is the number of rows to return

```
//will always return 1 row. note your orders

$q = "SELECT whatIwant FROM table WHERE id = 'myId' limit 0, 1";
```

http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm

Answer (score 3):

```
select whatIwant FROM table where id = 'myId' limit 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Well then leave out the loop:

```
$q = "select whatIwant FROM table where id = 'myId'";
$r = mysql_query($q);
$i = mysql_fetch_array($r);
$j = $i['whatIwant'];
echo $j;
```

This will only fetch the first line.

Answer (score 2):

`mysql_fetch_assoc()` is exactly what you're looking for.

http://php.net/mysqli_fetch_assoc

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php

Answer (score 0):

select whatIwant FROM table where id = 'myId' LIMIT 1;

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql224="select * from z_category order by id asc LIMIT 1";
$res224=mysql_query($sql224);
$rw224=mysql_fetch_array($res224);
$activeid2= $rw224['pkid'];
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

```php
$lastvalue = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id FROM  list ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1");

$row      = mysqli_fetch_array($lastvalue);

print_r ($row['id']);
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.